# Heroku Procfile Web Process for Springboot Application

Tags: heroku

I'm deploying a Springboot Application to Heroku and getting this error message:

> 2020-06-26T09:26:58.880610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to >crashed
> 2020-06-26T12:16:58.291701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to >starting
> 2020-06-26T12:17:05.611518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command >`java -war target/InfinityBank-1.0.war`
> 2020-06-26T12:17:08.625648+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults >based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
> 2020-06-26T12:17:08.635316+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: ->Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> 2020-06-26T12:17:08.635417+00:00 app[web.1]: Unrecognized option: -war
> 2020-06-26T12:17:08.635449+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not create the Java >Virtual Machine.
> 2020-06-26T12:17:08.635471+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: A fatal exception has >occurred. Program will exit.
> 2020-06-26T12:17:08.710255+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
> 2020-06-26T12:17:08.767963+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to >crashed

It looks like something is wrong with my Procfile. This is the only line inside the Procfile:

```
web: java -war target/InfinityBank-1.0.war
```

This is where I'm confused about. I actually don't know what the web process should be for my application.

An article from the Heroku website says it should be

> This might be the web process type for an executable Java JAR file, such as when using Spring Boot:

```
web: java -jar target/myapp-1.0.0.jar
```

Article link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#more-process-type-examples

I'm not sure what this means in my case. I don't see such a jar file anywhere in my source code. If it matters, my application is war packaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured this out in case anyone faces the same problem. You can find the jar file in your pom.xml file. For example, if you find this section in your pom.xml file

```
<groupId>space.earth</groupId>
    <artifactId>InfinityBank</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>InfinityBank</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
```

The jar file in the Procfile should be

```
web: java -jar target/InfinityBank-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Another tip for deploying jar packaging Springboot application to Heroku is to include

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

in the application.properties file.